# how to auto explode the jboss deployment

Tags: jboss

I have a war file (MyApp.war). While deploying in jboss, it is still
in compressed format. But in tomcat it is exploding 
and creates a **MyApp** folder. Is there any way to do that in **Jboss eap 5.1**?

Comment: If you are using JBoss AS 7 or JBoss EAP 6+, you'll see a `MyApp.war.deployed` file besides the war. In JBoss the file remains inside the deployments folder as it is but you'll notice from the file I mentioned that is is deployed successfully otherwise you get `MyApp.war.failed` if the deployment failed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you will find for web applications an exploded version of your war under **JBOSS_HOME\standalone\tmp\work\jboss.web[host-name]**. This is also the place where you will find JSP files converted as Servlets. The tmp filesystem is used internally by the application server to store the VFS (Virtual File System) storage. For more info about JBoss storage have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/jboss-as-storage-hints). Hope it helps.